# Conditionally bind class with Vue.js + Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuetify.js

I'm trying to conditionally apply the class "xs10" to a v-flex which contains my menu, based on the dimensions of the current screen. I've so far got something like this:

```
<v-flex v-bind:class="{ xs10: menuSmall}" fluid>

..data() {
 return {
  menuSmall: this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp
 }
}
```

But it's not working. I'm new to Vue.js + Vuetify but I'm guessing it's because menuSmall is not being re-calculated and re-rendered on every screen resize. Do I need to put it into the 'mounted' life-cycle of my Vue instance to make this work?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you will find your anwser at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137224/how-to-specify-different-margin-for-different-screen-sizes-using-breakpoint-in-v

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try

```
<v-flex v-bind:class="flexClass" fluid>  // Could also be just :class="flexClass"

computed: {
  flexClass(){
    return {
      xs10: this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just looking through docs, it seems xs10 should be applied to `<v-flex>` as an attribute, not a class.

[Vuetify layout grid, example #1, view source](https://vuetifyjs.com/layout/grid)
[Vue conditional attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

```js
<v-flex :xs10="menuSmall" fluid>

..data() {
 return {
  menuSmall: this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp
 }
}
```