# How to specify different margin for different screen sizes using breakpoint in Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a loop displaying specified amount of cards.

The problem is with `ma-5` attribute in `<v-flex>`. On `xs` screen size this margin is too big. How do I specify a different margin for different screen sizes?

#### Code:

```html
   <v-container>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4 ma-5 v-for="card in filteredCards" :key="card.id">
          <v-card flat class="elevation-20 test">
            <v-card-media :src="card.image" height="200px">
            </v-card-media>
            <v-card-title primary-title class="pa-4">
               <div>
                  <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{card.title}}</h3>
                  <div style="min-height:50px;">{{card.description}}</div>
               </div>
            </v-card-title>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
   </v-container>
```

#### What I've Tried:

---

I added this code below (copied from [this](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1434) page)

```html
<v-flex xs12 sm6 md4 v-for="card in filteredCards" :key="card.id"
   :class="{'ma-0': $breakpoint.smAndDown, 'ma-5': $breakpoint.mdAndUp}">
```

and I get these errors:

```html
[Vue warn]: Property or method "$breakpoint" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'smAndDown' of undefined"

TypeError: Cannot read property 'smAndDown' of undefined
```

---

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown`

Notice `$vuetify`

In your case:

```html
<v-flex 
    v-for="card in filteredCards"
    :key="card.id"
    :class="{'ma-0': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown, 'ma-5': $vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp}"
    xs12 sm6 md4  
>
```

Check [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/layout/grid) (Breakpoint object)

Comment: Ah! Brilliant, it works. Thank you! I wish it would be somewhere in the Vuetify docs though.

Comment: Oops, I see it now, I've been looking for it on that page, but I was going through the API section and didn't know that you can actually use `$vuetify.breakpoint`. Good to know, thanks

Comment: @Traxo thanks for the hint. Came here looking for the thing how to programmatically change button style based on breakpoint. Done this: `<v-btn :block="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown">Send</v-btn>`

Comment: The problem with this method is, if you are server side rendering, the padding will "jump" when the client hydrates. Hopefully there is a css only solution some day.

Comment: @AmritKahlon Seems like a relevant issue: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3436 Try to see if workarounds work for you, I have not tried them. Also relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991071/vuetify-breakpoints-not-working-in-nuxt-js

Comment: @Traxo thanks, but I'm not sure the problem is solvable with js. If the server is generating the page, the javascript has no idea what size the client's viewport will be. The only real way to solve it would be with CSS I believe. In my case the breakpoints work, they are just incorrect.

Answer (score 10):

The helper classes apply margin or padding at a given breakpoint. These classes can be applied using the following format: {property}{direction}-{breakpoint}-{size}.

Comment: example `mx-md-2` , `py-sm-4`

Answer (score 9):

There is an easier way now:

```html
<v-card 
  v-for="card in filteredCards"
  :key="card.id"
  class="ma-0 ma-md-5"
>
{{card.title}}
</v-card>
```

this applies margin of 0 for XS and SM, and margin 5 for MD and up

Answer (score 1):

In **Vuetify** this is named **Spacing**

You can see the [docs here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/)

#### Spacing

> Update your layout without creating new classes. Spacing helpers are useful for modifying the padding and margin of an element.

#### How it works

> The helper classes apply margin or padding to an element ranging from 0 to 16. Each size increment was designed to align with common Material Design spacings. These classes can be applied using the following format `{property}{direction}-{size}`.

#### Example

`ma-lg-8` means that the **margin** will be 8 when the screen is wider than `lg` breakpoint. Below that, the **margin** will be 3 --> `ma-3`

```
<template>
  <v-container class="ma-3 ma-lg-8">
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        {{ someRandomText }}        
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

You can also try adding them as attributes `<v-container ma-3 ma-lg-8>`, instead of in the `class`, it worked for me.