# Vuetify breakpoints not working in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a project using *Nuxt.js* as SSR engine and *Vuetify* as styling framework. In one of my templates I have such code:

```
<v-layout row wrap align-center 
 :class="{ 'mb-4': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown }">...</v-layout>
```

As you can see, I want to apply **mb-4** class only if I am on small screens and smaller ones. But when I load this on desktop large screen and inspect element, this class is attached even though screen resolution does not match logic for applying this class. However, styling is back to expected when I resize browser window.

I've tried to manually dispatch **'resize'** event in lifecycle hook:

```
mounted() {
   window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); 
}
```

But it didn't help. Even if I wrap it in `setTimeout`, still no luck.

**UPD:** found a workaround, but still think it is not the best solution:
changed

```
:class="{ 'mb-4': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown }"
```

to

```
:class="{ 'mb-4': isMounted && $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown }"
```

and in `mounted` lifecycle hook added: `this.isMounted = true`

UPDATE: while digging in Vuetify source code found out, that it checks window width with 200ms delay as window width check is costly operation. That is why we have delay.

Comment: I don't really see it as a bad solution. Another alternative is to remove that class from your <v-layout> and add a tag like this <div class="mb-4 hidden-sm-and-down" />

Comment: @SamirHaddad, problem is that with current approach content jumps because of some delay of applying classes according to vuetify breakpoint

Comment: Oh okay, I get you. I think placing your html tag inside the tag <no-ssr> may (or may not) solve your problem. https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-no-ssr/

Comment: It's due to the way Vue handles changing attributes with SSR, I'll hopefully have it fixed soon: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3436

Comment: It is fixed in Nuxt 2

Comment: this saved me! Thanks!! nuxt 2 still problematic

Answer (score 0):

you can give specific breakpoint for margin and padding attributes.

```
<v-layout row wrap align-center class="mb-sm-4">...</v-layout>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/#breakpoints