# vuetify: calculate grid width by passed props

Tags: vue.js, attributes, conditional-statements, vuetify.js

I want to make a menu component that builds same-sized buttons based on the amount of menuItems passed in as props.

similar to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47215040/6066886
i want to give the v-flex a conditional attribute. (xs6 for two items, xs4 for three and so on)

(something like `<v-flex v-for="item in menuItems" xs[12 / menuItems.length]>`)

in the linked question, the idea is to pass "xs10" or not, based on a condition.

i want to calculate WHICH of those will be added to my v-flex, but i have no idea how that would be done.. as i can't v-bind anything... can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, don't work for you the `xs{{12/menuItems.length}}` solution (you have to change the order)? If you have 1 item, the element with expand, 2 elements 50%, etc.

Comment: where did you get this solution? i have never seen this expression... that looks what i am searching for... but intellij says "tag start is not closed", that seems not to be working (order was wrong though, you are right) "12/menuItems.length" doesn't work. the slash gets interpreted as kind of html tag.. breaks everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see your problem now. I was digging around a little and it's not easy to solve, cause the v-flex doesn't support params, it should be declared as a attribute and not class (as says this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/47215040/6058255).

As there as no way to create a attribute without value, like I said in the comment, and affter some tests, I will do as follow:

```
<v-flex v-bind:class="'xs'+12/menuItems.length" v-for="menuItem in menuItems">
            {{menuItem}}
</v-flex>
```

This should render the `v-flex` element with a class like: `"xs12","xs6","xs4"`..

The then you should only `copy` the class style for this elements that have the `v-flex` for it, something like:

```
.xs12{ max-width:100%; }
.xs6{ max-width: 50%; }
.xs4{ max-width: 25%; }
.xs3{ max-width: 33.333333333%;  }
...
```

Maybe is not the `more elegant` solution but it's easy and it works for you I think.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

Reviewing `stdob--` answer I now see that only with the expression:

```
<v-flex v-bind:class="'xs'+12/menuItems.length" v-for="menuItem in menuItems">
            {{menuItem}}
</v-flex>
```

Should work. The flex component will render as `flex xs12` (for instance).

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a computed property as class object:

```
<v-flex :class="xsComputed" v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i">{{item}}</v-flex>


...

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    xsComputed: function() {
      var step = Math.floor(10 / this.items.length)
      var xsc = {}
      xsc['xs' + step] = true
      console.log(xsc)
      return xsc
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/26zfLn8j/